# How do I setText() in an textView from a DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I have a custom DialogFragment with a couple of options inside of it. The user is simply presented with a "Done" button in the Dialog to signal that they have completed their choice and to resume the activity. I have a textView on the activity below the dialog. My first thought was to use either a database (overkill) or sharedPreferences, but sharedPreferences is not an option in my specific case. So, my question is how do I setText on an textView from a DialogFragment with no sharedPreferences. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done via `Interface`:

In your `DialogFragment` class:

```
public interface OnDoneClickListener {
    void onDoneClicked() {}
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try {
        mCallback = (OnDoneClickListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        Log.d("Error", "activity must implement OnDoneClickListener");
    }
}
```

Now simply put `mCallback.onDoneClicked()` in your desire `onClick` event.

Back to your `Activity` which need to implement `OnDoneClickListener`,

```
@Override
public void onDoneClicked() {
    tv.setText("Done Clicked!!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an AlertDialog (simplest) then you just need to provide an onClickListener:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#AlertDialog

That page also has an example when using a more "standard" Fragment, basically call a method on the activity.

Comment: Yes, I understand the onClick listener will listen for the "Done" button to be hit, but it won't let me setText() to a textView on the activity.

Comment: If you're saying this because your Fragment is in a separate class, then either make the fragment a member of your activity or pass in the OnClickListener instance to the Fragment via a setter.

Comment: Hmm... is any way prefered or "easier" than the other? I'm not sure how to go about "making a fragment a member of my activity".

Comment: Just declare it somewhere in the Activity class so it can have access to the Activity's variables. However, the listener method is the preferred approach, and cleaner.

Comment: Alright, can you point me into some direction on how to "pass the onClickListener instance to the Fragment via a setter"? I don't really understand what that means/how to do that. Thanks again.